# Magento - Is it okay to disable Mage_Downloadable?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

In our Magento store we do not use any downloadable products and don't plan to.  Is it okay to completely disable the Mage_Downloadable module without causing any issues in the store?  I see no reason to spend processing time calling the observers and running code that will never get used...

Comment: Copy the files to a secondary location and test it out, see what happens.

Comment: I have disabled it in my dev site and it "seems" to be working properly, but you never know if doing something that seems ok may in fact cause an issue down the line.  I figured someone might have already disabled this extension with no problems or had experienced problems doing so and could help me avoid future problems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run find in path in any ide in `\app\etc\modules` for `Mage_Downloadable`. If no one your installed extension depends on it - you can disable it. If some module depends - you will find xml file with

```
<depends>
...
    <Mage_Downloadable />
...
</depends>
```

inside.

Comment: I"m not sure I'd rely on depends to correctly catch every dependency code in one module might have for another.

Comment: In case of core/enterprise modules I'd rely on it (for CE 1.5+ at least), but you are right, it is not the case for community ones.

Comment: @Zyava - what Alan is saying is that there is nothing imperative regarding `<depends>` usage. It simply causes configuration files to have precedence, which has some knock-on effects. Your answer is a good starting point, but a thorough answer would have someone do a case-insensitive search through all code for 'downloadable'.